# How to set up web2py for multi-tenant app with the tenant name coming after the domain name and not as a subdomain?

Tags: python, web2py, multi-tenant

For example:
 - https://domain.com/usergroupname/controller_name/function_name 
where usergroupname signifies the tenant name.

I've been trying to get it right for weeks but havent been able to get anything to work.

Edit:
To explain further, I have gotten multitenancy to work in subdomain format through the common field option in the model, but due to constraints (SSL certificates for each new tenant), I don't think its practical to have it set up that way.

So here's the content of routes.py that I've setup to try and get it to work.

`routers = dict(
     BASE = dict(
         default_application='myapp',
     )
routes_in = (
                ('/$domain','/myapp/workspaces/index/$domain'),
                ('/$domain/$c','/myapp/$c/index/$domain'),
                ('/$domain/$c/$f','/myapp/$c/$f/$domain'),
                ('/$domain/$c/$f/$anything','/devassist/$c/$f/$domain/$anything')
)

routes_out = [(a,b) for (b,a) in routes_in]`

Not sure what I'm missing though.

Comment: Which web2py mechanism have you tried, and in what way did it fail?

Comment: I tried using routes in and routes out in the routes.py file.

Comment: Maybe if you showed what you tried, someone could help you fix it.

Comment: Added further explanation above

Comment: You seem to be trying to use *both* the parameter-based system and the pattern based one simultaneously, with illegal Python code to boot.

Comment: Ok. Do you say that because of the `routers = dict( BASE = dict( default_application='myapp', )' line? Also please explain illegal python code.

Comment: Have you tried to evaluate this .py file?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to use a single app across all tenants, and the problem is that web2py uses what you want to be the usergroupname to identify the app.

The solution is to use web2py's URL rewriting facilities: http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#URL-rewrite